# Call 3rd party api which is not part of project Eureka registry via Feign client

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-feign, openfeign

I need to invoke 3rd party api e.g.: https://google.com.systems.uk/some-api/....  (this is fake api but yes 3rd party service).

This api is not part of my microservices and is not registered on my eureka registry and I have not included any routing path for it in my gateway.

I need to invoke this api from my feign client but getting error

`com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client:google.com.systems.uk`

my feign client code:

```
@FeignClient(value = "https://google.com.systems.uk/some-api/",
        decode404 = true)
public interface DataFeign {
    @GetMapping("/query11")
    Object getData(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String someToken, @RequestBody Body queryBody);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out answer for it.
use

```
@FeignClient(value = "Google" url = "https://google.com.systems.uk/some-api/",
        decode404 = true)
public interface DataFeign {
    @GetMapping("/query11")
    Object getData(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String someToken, @RequestBody Body queryBody);
}
```

url attribute of feign will help in invoking external api's.
For calling api's of services registered with your registry you can use value or name attribute.